# Limiting the nested fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to index json documents in ElasticSearch with dynamic mappings on. Some of the documents have unpredictable number of keys (nested levels) because of which I started getting this error from ES Java api.

`[ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=Limit of total fields [1000] in index [my_index] has been exceeded]]]failure in bulk execution`

I was wondering if there is an option which can be configured at index level where I can define to scan for fields only till certain level (maybe 2) and store the rest of the document as a string or in flattened form. I did come across some settings like `index.mapping.depth.limit` but it seems if I set it to 2, this setting rejects the document if there are more levels. [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/index-mapping-depth/145766)

Answer (score 3):

**For Total Field**

```
PUT <index_name>/_settings
{
  "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 2000
}
```

**For depth limit**

```
PUT <index_name>/_settings
{
  "index.mapping.depth.limit": 2
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/mapping.html

Comment: Came across this as mentioned in the question. This document rejects the documents for indexing if the depth is found more than 2 then. Here is the link https://discuss.elastic.co/t/index-mapping-depth/145766

Comment: You can make it allow inserting with the mapping setting `"dynamic": true` this will allow it to save all information, but index only a certain depth, this only this depth will be searchable.

Comment: This is to increase the limit after the index has been created. Is there a way to change the default setting so that new indices automatically pick the updated value?

Comment: To ensure that index settings are set for each new index you have to create an `_index_template` - or `_template (legacy)` . See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your index *_settings*:

```
"settings": {
    "index.mapping.nested_fields.limit": 150,
    ...
}
"mappings": {
...
}
```